# Problem accessing variables stored in event log

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, etherscan

I have succesfully implemented an event in my contract Portfolio:

```
// Define eventlog for myEvent
event myEvent(uint indexed eventDate, address indexed sender, myArray[] eventList, uint eventBalance);


function setEvent() public {
    // Function to track event 
    myEvents.push(now) -1;

    uint totalBalance = getTotalBalance();

    emit myEvent(now, msg.sender, myArray, totalBalance);
    }
```

The event is being created succesfully. I can find it in the Etherscan (Ropsten). I can retrieve the events from web3 and if there are multiple events see them. I have added the ABI and use the following code to read the events:

```
    function getEventClick() {
        $("#loader").show();

        myPortfolio.myEvent({}, { fromBlock: 0 }).get((errGetEvent, resGetEvent) => {
            if (!errGetEvent) {
                for (var p=0;p<resGetEvent.length;p++)
                    {
                    console.log(resGetEvent[p]);
                    }    

                $("#loader").hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

If I look in the console I see the event. My question is though, how do I access one of the event variable? For example eventDate? I tried the format resGetEvent[p][0] but that does not work.

@smarx the output looks something like this:

"47966a823fc8fa850a44428b5cb3b30efedb40248b6a9f867e7341a7ca1608", blockNumber: 6453810, logIndex: 30, removed: false, …}address: "0x714e7201582e138e5g3177c1f98370f14735fa69"args: eventBalance: X {s: 1, e: 12, c: Array(1)}myArray: ["0xb045ca6e22fbb0cbeabc6ec32923d86948c0b423"]eventDate: X {s: 1, e: 9, c: Array(1)}sender: "0x6d4dcc21e77ee5bc18d0d91497fc5285a71c836a"**proto**: ObjectblockHash: "0x0547966a822fc8fa850a44758b5cb3b30efedb40248b6a9f867e7341a7cb1608"blockNumber: 6454880event: "myEvent"logIndex: 30removed: falsetransactionHash: "0xa75d74264e05807e87d32135f9c1b9ed242af67584dcbb42cca9303ed0ee5c44"transactionIndex: 19__proto__: Objectconstructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()**defineGetter**: ƒ **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: ƒ **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: ƒ **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: ƒ **lookupSetter**()get **proto**: ƒ **proto**()set **proto**: ƒ **proto**()
(index):5348

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(resGetEvent[p])`? That should hopefully make it clear.

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I added the output.

Comment: The formatting makes it a bit hard, but it looks like `resGetEvent[p].args.eventDate` is what you want?

Comment: Yes! That works! Thank-you soooo much!!!